# How to access an object from a parent object constructor

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype, parent-child

Can I access the list object of the parent-object (TodoList) inside the prototype of a child-object (Todo)

Presume the next setup:

index.js :

```
var todoList = new TodoList(form,holder);
```

todolist.js :

```
function TodoList(form,holder){
  this.list = {};
  this.inputField = document.querySelector('input');
  this.submitButton = document.querySelector('button');
  this.todoHolder = holder;
  this.init();
}

TodoList.prototype.init = function(){
  this.submitButton.addEventListener('click',this.submitHandler.bind(this));
}

TodoList.prototype.submitHandler = function(e){
  var todo = new Todo(this.inputField.value, this.todoHolder);
}
```

todo.js :

```
function Todo(value, holder){
  this.id = nr++;
  this.value = value;
  this.checked = false;
  this.holder = holder;
  this.todoElement = "";
  this.template = `
    <li id="todo-{{id}}">
      <span>{{value}}</span>
      <a href="#" class="delete"></a>
      <a href="#" class="check"></a>
    </li>`;
  this.add(this.value);
}

Todo.prototype.add = function(value){
  //addToDom
  var html = this.template;
  this.holder.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html.replace('{{value}}',value).replace('{{id}}',this.id));
  this.setUpEventListeners();
  ////// QUESTION
  // HOW CAN I ACCESS THE TODOLIST.LIST object here
  // I KNOW I COULD DO todoList.list (but that is by the instance that was created. Is it possible by accessing parent or something like that....      
}
```

Comment: are you using a module loader, like require ? as your code is in separate files, you would likely need some type of module either common.js or AMD

Comment: You could just pass the parent `TodoList` as a parameter of the `Todo` constructor.  Both your current parameters are members of the `TodoList` anyway.

Comment: so how do you access todolist in the index file ?

Comment: @Tibrogargan can you please show me what you mean?

Comment: @saj For now we use 3 js files.

Comment: Pretty much what @KevinJantzer has for an answer :)  I might just use the one parent parameter, there doesn't seem to be a lot of point to the others .. especially since you could implement getters in the parent for both those values if you needed to be able to change them dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent object that creates the TODO should add a reference, like so:

```
TodoList.prototype.submitHandler = function(e){
  var todo = new Todo(this.inputField.value, this.todoHolder);
  todo.parent = this
}
```

Now this won't work in your current setup as your `add` method is being calling in the constructor which is before the `todo.parent` has been set.

So to get around this you should pass it in on the init of the Todo instead

```
TodoList.prototype.submitHandler = function(e){
  var todo = new Todo(this, this.inputField.value, this.todoHolder);
}
```

Which means this would be:

```
function Todo(parent, value, holder){
  this.parent = parent 
  // rest of logic...
}

Todo.prototype.add = function(value){
  console.log(this.parent)
}
```

Comment: I think it really should just pass itself as an argument when calling `add`. It's not necessary to store the parent on the instance, is it?